# Python - How to allow the use of a function in different modules?

Tags: python, function, module, package

I have 2 scripts.

```
Main.py
Update.py
```

I have a function in **Main.py** which basically does the following:

```
def log(message):
   print(message)
   os.system("echo " + message + " >> /logfile.txt")
```

And in the **Update.py** file I have a single function which basically does the update. However throughout the update function, it calls "log(message)" with whatever the message is at that point.

The problem now though is I'm getting a **NameError: global name "log" is not defined** whenever I try use the function outside of the **Main.py** script.

Any help? on how I would be able to use the function 'log' wherever?

*Code simplified for explanation.

**EDIT:**

```
Main.py imports Update from /Scripts/Update.py
Update.py imports log from Main.py
```

When i try this, it fails saying "cannot import name Update"

Comment: Root directory. Then /Scripts/ folder contains the Update.py script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't* import `log` from `Main`. That'll rerun the code in Main.py, since running Main.py as a script and importing it as a module aren't equivalent. Other modules should not depend on functions defined in the main script. Instead, put your `log` function in another module and import that, or have Main.py explicitly pass a logger to the other modules somehow.

**Update**: You can't import `Update` because Python can't find it. Python checks in [4 places](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for modules to import, but the ones you should be interested in are

- the directory the script was from, and
- the directories specified in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

You'll either need to put Main.py and the things it imports in the same directory, or add `/Scripts` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add in **Update.py** the line

```
from Main import log
```

and you will be able to call `log()` from Update.py.

Answer (score 1):

You should import the function:

```
from Main import log
```

Or best:

```
import Main
Main.log()
```

For modules importing each other, refer [How can I have modules that mutually import each other](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other).

Comment: Tried that. It does some weird error.

Basically. If I import the Update function in my Main script. then try import the log function in the update script. it does a weird cycle and errors out trying to import the update function.

Comment: Updated, please check and refer the link.@Skowt